# Get image of another application running

Tags: android, .net, powershell, scripting, adb

I am trying to find a non blocking way to get a image of the display of another application.

The goal is to get an android emulator screenshot without using the android screenshot function (it is slow and blocking).

Comment: Use an Android app that uses the media projection API on Android 5.0+ and has some sort of a control mechanism that you can script. [My `andshooter` sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/FINAL/MediaProjection/andshooter) works this way, where the screen-capturing service can be controlled via `Intent` actions (see the `record` shell script).

Comment: is there a way outside of android to capture a window's display. Like if chrome is up i can capture what it is displaying?

Comment: If you mean literally capturing the entire emulator window, that would depend on your desktop operating system. On Linux, for example, [you may be able to use `scrot`](http://xmodulo.com/take-screenshot-command-line-linux.html).